# Pickle UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, pickle

I want to store a Python object that contains several `numpy` arrays in a file. I found `pickle` but I'm always getting an `UnicodeDecodeError` when loading a stored object:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "system.py", line 46, in <module>
  m2 = System.loadMemory('m1.pickle')
 File "system.py", line 28, in loadMemory
  memory = pickle.load(filehandler)
  File "/home/daniel-u1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in
   decode (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Method `saveMemory` works fine, but `loadMemory` throws the error at `pickle.load`:

```
@staticmethod
def saveMemory(m1, filename):
    filehandler = open(filename, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(m1, filehandler)

@staticmethod
def loadMemory(filename):
    filehandler = open(filename, 'r')
    memory = pickle.load(filehandler)
    return memory
```

Has anyone an idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Why are you writing the file in binary mode and reading in text mode?

Comment: In other words, use `open(filename, 'rb')` to open the file in `loadMemory()`.

Comment: @martineau Thank you very much, that was the thing. Could you please answer in a separate post so I can mark this as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you wrote the file binary mode (`'wb'`) but then try to read it back in as text mode (`'r'`). So to fix it all you should need to do is change one line:

```
@staticmethod
    def loadMemory(filename):
        filehandler = open(filename, 'rb')  # must read in binary mode, too
        memory = pickle.load(filehandler)
        return memory
```